# Symfony Ajax Progress Bar

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, symfony

I have an ajax controller that iterate over a loop.
I would like to update a progress bar following this controller progress.

Basically, I just have to output a `$('.bar').css('width', $percent . '%')`.

But all those outputs are just accumulated and sent once the function is finished.

How can I update the bar after each output ?

I have already tried `flush()` and `ob_flush()`.

Does Symfony uses other buffers ?

EDIT: Part of the controller that ouput javascript

```
$total = count($results);
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $count++;
    echo '<script>$(\'.bar\').css(\'width\', \'' . (int)($count / $total * 100) . '%\');</script>';
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code how you do this in AJAX?

Comment: I added my php controller. There is nothing on the javascript side.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work, the AJAX call will get the data back from PHP when it is done, so after the foreach loop.

Comment: Do you think there is no way to do this ?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? This controller is called only once ? Its seems like a fake progress bar, coz when you write "$total = count($results);" you have already load all results

Comment: Indeed, there are many other lines in the foreach, but they are not necessary to understand my issue. This loop make a lot of operations on the results, and this is what I want to have on my progress bar.

Comment: You should use session_write_close in your long ajax phpaction... With that, you can do a loop with another ajax to check the progress.

Comment: Thanks, do you have an exemple ?

Comment: I'll give one as answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use session-write-close() in your long php action.

JS :

```
var isInProgress = false;
function veryLongImport()
{
     isInProgress = true;
     checkfx();
     $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: /myverylongueactionPath ,
            async : true,
            cache: false,
            dataType:'html',
            success: function(data){},
            error: function(){  },
            complete: function(){
                isInProgress = false;
            }
        });
}

function checkfx()
{
    if( isInProgress != false )
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: /mycheckpath ,
            async : true,
            cache: false,
            dataType:'html',
            success: function(data){
                 makeYourProgressBarGrowHere();
             },
            error: function(){  },
            complete: function(){
                checkfx();
            }
        });
    } else { }
}
```

PHP Controller:

```
public function myVeryLongAction($id)
{
   session_write_close();
   ... code ...
}

public function myCheckAction()
{
    ...code...
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the snippets and sorry for the delay. What exactly am I supposed to do on the myCheckAction() ? Because all I want to analyse is in myVeryLongAction() ...

Comment: Ok I see, in myVeryLongAction(), I set a percent variable, and in myCheckAction(), I get it. The problem is that there are different calls of myCheckAction, I can't set a variable. The only solution would be a session varibale, but due to the session_write_close, it is not possible...

Comment: You can't set a variable directly in your controller ? YourClass{ protected $variable; public indexAction(){}... } ?

Comment: I tried, but on myCheckAction(), the variable always have the default value, maybe because this is a different call that myVeryLongAction(). I also tried with a session variable without session_write_close(), the variable is set to 100, the final value, but I don't have all the steps...

Comment: I was stupid with variable in controller, it won't save :/ ... One other way is to store variable in database, or a temp file... I used this function to get the last line in log file in reality...

Comment: I didn't think about this before, but I think it's a good way, I should think about it in my own code now...

Comment: For some reason, the static variable doesn't not work... They are definitively two differents executions. Last hope is to use cookie. Thanks for all, your method work, let's find a way to save those percents ;)

Comment: @apfz A working method ? The code here just need to be implemented, after it's your job. OR the job of someone your have to hire.